# Simple Keyword-URL Generator PHP

Tags: php, url-shortener

### Here's what I have so far:

Admin Section:
 Login system
 Form to insert: LongURL, Keyword, Username, Password, Timestamp

User Section:
 Login System
 Table to show links they have that are active for that user

The above works fine, but they're just records, not actual working links.

### My Goal:

To know how to turn the records into actual links. So, when a general web user goes to the short link (e.g. short.co/biz1) they get redirected to the longURL.

I've seen people suggesting using **.htaccess** ways, but I'm confused as to why I can't just have a php page that takes everything after the '/', finds a record that matches it on the database and forwards the user to that page?

I've been trying to get this sorted for a few days, and every blog I read just gets me more confused, so any help would be great.

Thanks in advance

Comment: BTW: My keywords will contain no special characters, just letters and numbers, and will not have any further '/' in the URL.

Comment: you need .htaccess, because only it can redirect all routes to one file, I don't think there's any faster way

Answer (score 2):

Url shortening is a stupid not magical thing:

Create a database table: id, url where id is an auto increment value.

Then use id in urls and redirect to the original url. To get the urls even more *short* I would use a number system like base25 in urls to shorten the integers.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate some short random string and store it in database also. Then when generating second short url you need to check whether the short url already exists. If it does you need to generate new and then store it in database. Then you will get the string with `$_GET[]` e.g. example.com/2uzt3a or example.com/?u=2uzt3a. It is up to you. Then you will just run query with that string, get the long url and redirect